# How to download a file at a specified location through Python and Selenium using Chrome driver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drive

I am automatically downloading some links through a website and it is getting saved by default in Download directory but I want to save those links to the desired location as per the need. I am using Python 3.

I am using this code but it is not working.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C://Users//ASUS//Downloads")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

Any type of help will be appreciated.

Thank you..

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: okey sir i'll remember from now onwards. @halfer

Answer (score 0):

As per your code trial you have set the `download.default_directory` through an instance of **ChromeOptions** while initializing the *WebDriver* and *WebBrowser* instance which remains unchanged throughout the lifespan of the *WebDriver* and *WebBrowser* instance.

While the *WebDriver* and *WebBrowser* instance is active even if you are able to extract any of the *capabilities* or other *session attributes* from the current *Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change any of those attributes of the currently active *WebDriver* instance e.g **download.default_directory**. If you want to change any of the *capabilities* or other *session attributes* you have re-configure the *WebDriver* instance again.

Comment: Update the question with your current code attempts as what you  _have done_ along with the error (if any)